# Show Query Results in Textbox on form

Tags: ms-access

I am putting together a Microsoft Access 2010 DB.  It is to contain our timesheets with various fields:

```
username,payroll_id,fname,lname,number,group,local_date,local_day,local_start_time,local_end_time,tz,hours,jobcode,inventory item,inventory item #2,inventory item #3,inventory item #4,location,notes,approved_status
```

The current task I'm tackling is I'd like to display 'Totals' on the main form.  I've made queries to find the information I need, I'd like to find a way to show the results from a query in a text box I can have on the form.  To look something like this

Label:  (Plain Text) | Query Result:  (Text Box)

### Total Records to date:  | 50

### Total Records this week:  | 10

The queries just run a simple 'COUNT' on the 'jobcode' column within MASTER-AllData Table.

Should I be looking to do this from queries via Control Set in text box properties or should I just use 'DLookup' and put a forumla in there?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
TIA
Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a single value from a query (that returns a single record), `DLookup` is the best choice. E.g.

```
=DLookup("mySum", "mySumQuery")
```

If the queries are simple enough, you might also get rid of them and use their criteria directly in a `=DCount(...)` formula in the textboxes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I tried =DCount([jobcode],[Master-AllData],"Not Null")
I didn't get any syntax errors however when I view the form it shows #Name?  rather than the result?  Am I making a mistake in the formula do you think or is there some other config I need to make to the text box?

Comment: I entered =DCount([jobcode],[Master-AllData],"Not Null") into Control Source - should I do that or should it be in Default Value?

Comment: No, Control source is correct. You are on the right track, but your criteria is not valid. It must be `"SomeField Is Not Null"`. Switch your original query to SQL mode and check there. Also, with DCount it is generally best and most efficient to use `"*"` as expression (1st parameter).